# Removing element from ArrayList Java Processing Boid example

Tags: java, deployment, processing

- Got this BOID application going in Processing with some steering algorithms.

[image]

- The boids are stored
  in two separate ArrayLists for each colour.
- The red boid (predator) has a
  pursue function:

  ```
  class Creature {
     int prey = 1;
     PVector pursue(ArrayList boids) {

         PVector steer = new PVector();
         if (prey < boids.size()) {
           Creature boid = (Creature) boids.get(prey);
           steer = PVector.sub(boid.location, location);
           steer.mult(maxpursue);
      }
      return steer;
    }
  ```

This function gets the red boids to stand on top of the targeted white boid.

**The problem is getting this white boid to disappear when all the red boids are on top of it. (Like shown in the image above)**

I can add a new boid or predator with the following, but i cannot remove?:

```
void mousePressed() {

   if (mouseButton == LEFT){
      Creature predator = new Creature(mouseX, mouseY, 2); 
      planet.boids.add(predator);
   } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
      Creature boid = new Creature(mouseX, mouseY, 1);
      planet.boids.add(boid);
      planet.boids.remove(boid);  // This line does not work?
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create an instance, add it and then immediately remove it from the list anyway?

Comment: Now you have edited the code so that `planet.boids.remove(boid);` isn't actually part of any method. Please post the *actual code* you claim does not work.

Comment: This was just for testing. If i remove the creation of a new instance, then it cannot recognize 'predator'.. And I don't know how to change the code so that it does.  Tried stuff like..

planet.boids.add(Creature predator); , 

planet.boids.add(Creature.predator);


?

Comment: @AndyTurner this is only a snippet of all the code. I don't see why the rest is needed?

Comment: Don't you see why it might help for you to post the code which you say doesn't work?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: Just a bit of advice, try to write a unit test getting rid of a boid in your arrayList, this may shine some light on your problem.

Comment: "This line does not work?" What does "does not work" mean? It does work, it just doesn't do what you think it ought to. What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens instead? What is the return value of that method?

Comment: To accomplish this, you would likely need a method that iterates through the list of white boids and checks if the red boids are on top of it. If `true`, `planet.boids.remove(indexOfBoid);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't make a ton of sense. You want to remove an **existing** `Boid`, so why on earth are you creating a new one and then immediately removing it?

You haven't posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I can only answer in a general sense, but here's what you need to do:

**Step 1:** Refactor your code so that it makes more sense. Comment every single line if you have to, just to be sure you know exactly what the code is doing. But you shouldn't be doing things like adding a new `Boid` and then removing it in the very next line. Break your problem down into smaller steps, and make sure each step works perfectly by itself before trying to mix it with other funtionality.

**Step 2:** Create a function that takes a single `white Boid` and the `List` of `red Boids`, and returns `true` if that `white Boid` should be removed. Test this function by itself using hard-coded values in a standalone example sketch.

**Step 3:** Iterate over your `white Boids` and call the function you created in step 2 for each one. If the function returns true, then remove that `white Boid`. You might want to use an `Iterator` for this step.

If you get stuck on one of those steps, then post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a **specific question**, and we'll go from there. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions, but it's much easier to answer specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions- especially if we have an MCVE we can actually run on our own machines instead of some disconnected snippets.